# Exception java.text.ParseException when parsing datetime input type in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, datetime, servlets

I am getting exception `java.text.ParseException` when parsing datetime input type in JSP page. I need to store date in the database but I could not.

```
<input type="datetime-local" required="required" name="TAT" >
```

Java code:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("E MM-dd-yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a");
String parameter = request.getParameter("TAT");
Date date = fmt.parse(parameter);
System.out.println(fmt.format(date));
```

I could not get it as Date and time format to store.

Comment: which formate are you looking for store ? i.e. mm/dd/yyy or else ?

Comment: can you show me what is value of request.getParameter("TAT") are we getting ?